# Tkinter window is blank when running

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, refresh, adafruit

When I run my tkinter code for measuring the temperature with Adafruit. When I run my code tkinter opens a window but nothing appears on the window. I have used tkinter a bit before and I have had what is supposed to appear appear but just not in this particular code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
k= StringVar()
num = 1
thelabel = Label(root, textvariable=k)
thelabel.pack

def READ():
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
    newtext = "Temp=%s*C Humidity=%s" %(t,h)
    k.set(str(newtext))
    print newtext #I added this line to make sure that newtext actually had the values I wanted

def read30seconds():
    READ()
    root.after(30000, read30seconds)

read30seconds()
root.mainloop()
```

And to clarify the print line in READ does run ever 30 seconds as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is because you are not packing it in the window but you are printing it in the python shell.

you should replace that `print newtext` with:

```
w = Label(root, text=newtext)
w.pack()
```

a working code should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
k= StringVar()
num = 1
thelabel = Label(root, textvariable=k)
thelabel.pack

def READ():
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
    newtext = "Temp=%s*C Humidity=%s" %(t,h)
    k.set(str(newtext))
    w = Label(root, text=newtext)
    w.pack() 


def read30seconds():
    READ()
    root.after(30000, read30seconds)

read30seconds()
root.mainloop()
```

note that this is a very basic code graphically speaking.
to learn more about this topic visit this [tkinter label tutorial](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)
and to learn more about tkinter itself visit this [introduction to tkinter](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/)

if you want the label to be overwritten everytime it is refreshed you should use the `destroy()` method to delete and then replace the Label like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import Adafruit_DHT as dht
import time
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
k= StringVar()
num = 1
thelabel = Label(root, textvariable=k)
thelabel.pack

def READ():
    global w
    h,t = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, 4)
    newtext = "Temp=%s*C Humidity=%s" %(t,h)
    k.set(str(newtext))
    print newtext #I added this line to make sure that newtext actually had the values I wanted

def read30seconds():
    READ()
    try: w.destroy()
    except: pass
    root.after(30000, read30seconds)

read30seconds()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but do you have any idea how to make it replace the line of temperature and humidity? That is why I had the k.set in my code but the result just continuously prints more and more lines.